# Fuse for linux not found in rpmforge repo

Tags: yum, fuse, rhel5

I am trying to install fuse via yum on our RHEL5 instance. Its not available in my yum list.

After checking, some sites suggests enabling rpmforge repo will provide the package in yum to install. I enabled rpmforge repo (latest for RHEL5), but there is no fuse in that as well.

I tried with EPEL repo as well, same result.

Can anyone help me to find the root cause of this?

Note: I can install fuse using src, but that is not working for the other software I am trying to install (s3fs), that's why I need the yum to get working so that I would have all the latest packages needed.

Thanks for the help.

-Noman A.

Comment: Have you looked at adding Fusion to your repositories?

Comment: I don't understand that, perhaps you are referring to something else. I am talking about FUSE (FileSystem in Userspace). Please correct me if I am wrong and you are referring to the same thing. If yes, would you please elaborate? Thanks for the response!

Comment: Fusion is Fedora based distro that has things that are not GPLed.  I looked and does not have what you are looking for, it was just an idea.

Comment: Thanks for looking ben, really appreciate it! hope I get some help here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FUSE (kmod-fuse) has moved from RPMforge to ELRepo, since ELRepo focusses on hardware enablement for RHEL and derivative distributions (like CentOS or Scientific Linux).

http://elrepo.org/

Beware that in more recent releases of RHEL5, FUSE is part of the kernel.